# DeleteObject does not exist in Context

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

i am using vs 2012 and dot net 4, i have a model folder that contains my model in my page " Default.aspx " i used

```
> using MyProjectName.Model;
```

but when i am trying to delete some data it says " DeleteObject " Method does not exist!

```
using (var context = new Entities())
                    {
                        (from ur in context.Module_Users_Info where ur.UserID == comarg select ur).ToList().ForEach(context.DeleteObject);

                    }
```

Comment: What type is `context`? It needs to be an `ObjectContext`

Comment: It's my model DbContext

Comment: Well that's the problem, `DbContext` doesn't have a `DeleteObject` method. You shouldn't really be using `DbContext` nowadays anyway it's a very limited version of `ObjectContext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `DbContext` you can use `DbSet<T>.Remove` instead of `ObjectContext.DeleteObject` which has the same purpose to delete entities from the database:

```
using (var context = new Entities())
{
    (from ur in context.Module_Users_Info
     where ur.UserID == comarg
     select ur)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(ur => context.Module_Users_Info.Remove(ur));
}
```

Comment: That's right, but why i could use my way in vs 2010 and i can not use it in vs 2012!??

Comment: @AProgrammer: It has nothing to do with VS, but with the Entity Framework version. You apparently used `ObjectContext` with VS2010 (which has `DeleteObject`), but `DbContext` (which has a different API) with VS2012. Google for "ObjectContext vs. DbContext" or so, to find more details.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) doesn't have a `DeleteObject` method, only [ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) does, you can get the underlying object context by casting e.g.

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.DeleteObject
```

Comment: but in vs 2010 when i create a model it will create codes and when i am using that codes it works good, now what should i do?

Comment: Presumably I shouldn't be using this workaround if this has been removed from the API for a good reason?